# Exporting geodatabase layer to shapefile fails in QGIS

Tags: qgis-3

I'm attempting to export a single layer from a geodatabase to a shapefile. The export fails at the same point, 71%, with this message (I'm only displaying the first few lines),

```
Export to vector file failed.
Error: Feature write errors:
Feature creation error (OGR error: Failed to write shape object. 
File size cannot reach 4294815324 + 162344.)
```

The export operation does produce a shapefile, but with only about 70% of the content of the original geodatabase layer.

I'm using a MacBook Pro, operating OS 10.15.2 and QGIS 3.4.15.

Comment: The 4,294,815,324 byte means 4 gigabytes +. Shapefile's limit storage is 2 gigabytes. That is why it cannot export the to shapefile. Check Geometry limitations in arcgis.help: https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/manage-data/shapefiles/geoprocessing-considerations-for-shapefile-output.htm